# How to get json values for keys from json nested structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, coffeescript

I am trying to get the specific json values for the specific keys from the json structure. I have tried the following:

```
var jsonstring;
jsonstring = JSON.stringify(myjsonObjectArray);
alert(jsonstring);//giving the below json structure

jsonstring = [{
    "key01": [10, "Key01 Description"],
    "key02": [false, "It's a false value"],
    "key03": [null, "Testing Null"],
    "key04": ["tests", "Another Test Value"],
    "key05": [
        [25, 50], "Some testing values"
    ]
}, {
    "key10": [100, "Key10 Value"],
    "key11": [true, "It's a true value for key11"],
    "key12": [null, "key12 values is Null"],
    "key13": ["Testing", "Another Test Value for key13"],
    "key14": [
        [10, 20], "Some other testing values"
    ],
    "key15": ["Test Name", "Name of the key15"]
}]
```

but I need like below structure:

```
jsonstring = [{
    "key01": 10,
    "key02": false,
    "key03": null,
    "key04": "tests",
    "key05": [25, 50]
}, {
    "key10": 100,
    "key11": true,
    "key12": null,
    "key13": "Testing",
    "key14": [10, 20],
    "key15": "Test Name"
}]
```

How can I get like above structure(means I need only single values, don't need the second values/multiple values for the respective keys from the structure) ? Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not coffeescript ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which *creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array* and to get the first item from array, manipulate it using `for..in` loop and extract `first-index-item` from array.

```js
var jsonstring = [{
  "key01": [10, "Key01 Description"],
  "key02": [false, "It's a false value"],
  "key03": [null, "Testing Null"],
  "key04": ["tests", "Another Test Value"],
  "key05": [
    [25, 50], "Some testing values"
  ]
}, {
  "key10": [100, "Key10 Value"],
  "key11": [true, "It's a true value for key11"],
  "key12": [null, "key12 values is Null"],
  "key13": ["Testing", "Another Test Value for key13"],
  "key14": [
    [10, 20], "Some other testing values"
  ],
  "key15": ["Test Name", "Name of the key15"],
  "key16": null, //Test Data
  "key17": 'Fake Name' //Test Data
}];
var op = jsonstring.map(function(item) {
  for (var i in item) {
    item[i] = Array.isArray(item[i]) ? item[i][0] : item[i]; //If `item[i]` is not an array
  }
  return item;
});
console.log(op);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried, but for me it's giving error like jsonstring.map is not a function in my CoffeScript. op = jsonstring.map((item) ->
          for i of item
            item[i] = if Array.isArray(item[i]) then item[i][0] else item[i]
          item
        )
        alert op

Comment: Yes I have solved that in my scripting as I am missing one variable in my code. Your code is working fine, Thanks you for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use functional CoffeeScript with lodash/fp.

HTML:

```
<script src='path/to/lodash.js'></script>
<script src='path/to/lodash.fp.js'></script>
```

then:

```
json = [
        key01: [10, 'Key01 Description']
        key02: [false, 'It\'s a false value']
        key03: [null, 'Testing Null']
        key04: ['tests', 'Another Test Value']
        key05: [
            [25, 50]
            'Some testing values'
        ]
    ,
        key10: [100, 'Key10 Value']
        key11: [true, 'It\'s a true value for key11']
        key12: [null, 'key12 values is Null']
        key13: ['Testing', 'Another Test Value for key13']
        key14: [
            [10, 20]
            'Some other testing values'
        ]
        key15: ['Test Name', 'Name of the key15']
]

convert = _.map _.mapValues _.first

alert JSON.stringify convert json
```

Lodash gives you helper functions for problems like that.
The fp variant allows you their combination, mostly by changing argument order.
That convert line means 'Map all values in the array by mapping all values of the containing objects by returning the first element of the values only', which is exactly what you wanted.

To try yourself:
https://jsfiddle.net/